# Get array value from a list of arrays

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, underscore.js

I have this code:

```
loadAccountTerms = (termsCode) ->
  if termsCode.length is 0 then return []
  hmgetPr( "buyers", termsCode )
    .then (accountTerms) ->
      console.log accountTerms
      terms = _(accountTerms).map( (pl,index) ->
        console.log pl["priceList"]
      )
```

Where `console.log accountTerms` returns

`[ '{"srCode":"","accountCode":"SHO005","priceList":"CART","discount":0,"termDays":0}' ]`

But when I loop through this and try to return the `priceList` I get undefined.

What am I missing?

Comment: accountTerms is having a single string value in array not a json object that is it should be `[{}]` not `['{}']`

Comment: What is `terms` and why do you assign to it? Why do you use `map` here? Why do you use Underscore at all where Coffeescript would be more succinct?

Comment: You must not `return []`, but return a **promise** for an empty array if there is no `termsCode`.

Answer (score 0):

> [
>   '{"srCode":"","accountCode":"SHO005","priceList":"CART","discount":0,"termDays":0}'
>   ]

is not what you should work on.

Try :

> [
>   {"srCode":"","accountCode":"SHO005","priceList":"CART","discount":0,"termDays":0}
>   ]

This way, it is a JSON object, not a string.

Comment: credits to Sami on OP post comment, he got it first.